# Throwing an Error inside the context of a closure is not reaching the catch clause

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am throwing an exception in the context of closure and can't catch it. Here is a trivial example.

```
try{
  setTimeout(function(){ throw Error() },100)
}
catch(error)
{
   console.log("YES",error);
}
```

It never makes it to the catch clause and causes my node process to terminate. Same issue here:

```
try{
  setTimeout(function(){undefinedMethod() },100)
}
catch(error)
{
   console.log("YES",error);
}
```

My real example is closer to this:

```
 try{
   var ctx={setTimeout:setTimeout};
   require('vm').runInNewContext("setTimeout(function(){undefinedMethod() },100)",ctx)  
 }
 catch(error)
 {
   console.log(error);
 }
```

I need the try/catch as safety measure. Currently this behaviour causes my node process to terminate. How can I catch the exception?

Comment: What about putting the try/catch inside the timeout?

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer to your question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10337225/5111146

The solution is too move the try catch into the method called on timeout.

Comment: I can't do that in my case.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. I'm not sure that throwing an error inside an anonymous function inside a timeout inside a try/catch would work.

Comment: I understand the issue. I just can't have the node.js process to terminate.

Comment: Why can't you use something like:
require('vm').runInNewContext("setTimeout(function(){try { undefinedMethod(); } catch(error) { console.log(error); } },100)",ctx)

Comment: Because this doesn't help if there other embedded closures. I like to have a safety belt as last measure, but it looks its not a possibility.

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js.  Does it have the onError event? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/951811/5111146)

Answer (score 0):

If the error is going to be consistent and can be handled in the code outside the vm context, global handler for unhandled exception and rejection can be used catch these errors.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', console.log);
process.on('uncaughtException',  console.log);
```